# How to get field as string regardless of it's content type in Java?

Tags: java, json

I am trying to retrieve a field from a JsonObject as String. This field "agentid" sometimes come as long and sometimes as String. When it comes as a long, I get an exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.CharSequence

Following is the statement which hits this exception:

```
// get agent ID
String agentID = parameterJson.getString("agentid");
```

How to safely get the content of this field "agentid" and store it as String in Java?

Comment: You can use `Double.toString(parameterJson.getDouble("agentid");` to store this as a String. However, you'll have to fit the method the the type of the object you want to parse.

Answer (score 1):

Depnding on which `JsonObject` class you are using, I'm assuming it has a `get()` or `getObject()` method that returns an `Object`. You can call that method followed by `.toString()`.

For example:

```
String agentID = parameterJson.getObject("agentid").toString();
```

Comment: It am getting java.lang.Double cannot be cast to io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject. Used code as you have suggested `String agentID = parameterJson.getJsonObject("agentid").toString();`

Comment: @user3243499 Perhaps you are not calling the right method. I don't know which class you are using, so I can't check it myself, but see if there's a method that returns an `Object` (not JsonObject).

Answer (score 1):

There are different things you can do:

For the first you can do `Double.toString(...)` because the `Exception` tells you why the error appears.

Also you can do `String.valueOf(Object)` that can also handle every object you pass in there or you just use the `toString` method when you get an `Object` from the JSON.

You also are able to just use the `getDouble` instead of `getString` and use the type double.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to convert it to string.

```
String agentID = String.valueOf(parameterJson.getString("agentid"));
```

Comment: `parameterJson.getString("agentid")` already returns a `String`, and throws an exception if the value of the given key is not a `String`.

Comment: This wouldn't work as you're doing a `getString(Double)`, it will still throw the exception, either `String.valueOf(Object)` or `Object.toString()` are the way to go